# Django annotate time delta by hours

Tags: django, django-views

I have a model as follows:

```
class WorkTime(models.Model):
   person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
   entry_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now(), verbose_name='date')
   start_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='start')
   end_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='end')
```

With data as follows:

```
person, date, start, end
1 01/01/2014 08:00 12:00
1 01/01/2014 13:00 18:00
1 02/01/2014 08:00 12:00
1 02/01/2014 13:00 18:00
1 03/01/2014 08:00 16:00
1 01/02/2014 08:30 12:00
1 01/02/2014 13:00 18:00
2 01/01/2014 09:00 13:00
2 01/01/2014 14:00 18:00
```

How would one sum up the time delta (i.e. end_time - start_time) and GROUP BY person to show the hours worked by person, as below?

```
person, hours
1 34:30
2 08:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a good way to do this in the ORM. It's pretty straight forward to build a dictionary by iterating through a queryset.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

totals = defaultdict()
work_times = WorkTime.objects.
for work_time in work_times:
    totals[work_time.person] += datetime.combine(work_time.entry_date, work_time.end_time) - datetime.combine(work_time.entry_date, work_time.start_time)

# print results
for person, total_time in totals.items():
    # total_time will be a timedelta, you can do some more work to return hours and minutes
    print person, total_time
```

Depending on your usage, the performance of this might be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is one way of doing it. 
Note that you can't just subtract model.TimeField values.  You have to convert to a date before doing such e.g. datetime.datetime.combine(work_time.date, work_time.end_time) - datetime.datetime.combine(work_time.date, work_time.start_time)

Comment: Another way is to store the delta in seconds in the model / database and then to annotate the delta.  Does anyone know how to annotate the delta without storing it in the db?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a while, but maybe someone will stumble upon this.
You can do it this way:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum
queryset = queryset.values('person').annotate(sum_delta=Sum(F('end_time')-F('start_time')).order_by('person__id')
```

This will sum up all timedeltas for each person and you dont have to store extra stuff in the db.